# How to detect if a string contains special characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to detect if a string contains special characters like #,$,^,&,*,@,! etc (non-alphanumeric characters) in SQL server 2005?

Comment: What do you consider *special?*

Comment: Every character is special in its own way. You're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: Ok, now it becomes »What does the ›etc.‹ refer to?«.

Comment: What flavour SQL are you using? SQL Server? mySQL?...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server:

e.g. if you class special characters as anything NOT alphanumeric:

```
DECLARE @MyString VARCHAR(100)
SET @MyString = 'adgkjb$'

IF (@MyString LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%')
    PRINT 'Contains "special" characters'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Does not contain "special" characters'
```

Just add to other characters you don't class as special, inside the square brackets

Comment: This answer confused me at first, because it uses `LIKE` but the ^ character in the brackets actually means 'NOT'

Comment: @AdaTheDev how do we exclude "-" from special characters in this scenario?

Comment: @aaronmallen, to exclude dashes from special characters, use `IF (@MyString LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9-]%')`

Comment: how do we exclude space

Comment: @aaronmallen To expand on Baodad's answer, characters that have a special meaning within square brackets can be included as characters to match by placing them somewhere where the special meaning doesn't apply.  So for '-', this would be at the very start or end of the list of characters.

Answer (score 20):

One way is for each special characters to be checked separately:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
    WHERE columnName LIKE "%#%" OR columnName LIKE "%$%" OR (etc.)
```

Comment: Nice, i used this code to simplify my problem. I was looking for this **á** :

`declare @letra char(1)
set @letra = 'á'

SELECT 
col1
,col2
,col3
 FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%' + @letra + '%' OR col2 LIKE '%' + @letra + '%' OR col3 like '%' + @letra + '%'
`

Answer (score 1):

In postgresql you can use regular expressions in WHERE clause.
Check http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html

MySQL has something simmilar: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html