# MySQL returning only 1 row, although it should more

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table.

```
Name    Surname Age
John    Gordon  22
Abbey   Gibson  43
Claude  Dickson 34
Jean    Huston  54
Georges Oak     35
Georges Lane    32
Cathy   Harper  12
Joseph  Gordon  11
Chloe   Lane    23
```

I am trying to run the following query:

`Select * from MyDB.myTable where myTable.Surname LIKE '%on'`

Assumable, this should return to me all the rows that have their surnames ending with `on`, however, I only get 1 row return.

Comment: Can you please attache the table definition ? Is there any trigger/stored procedure ecc. ?

Comment: No, nothing,  just a basic table.

Comment: what happens when you do like '%son' or you do  '%ton' or '%don'

Comment: I mean Surname is varchar ? I just tested with a varchar(100) with your test data and it worked.

Comment: Yes, it is varchar(50)

Comment: How was the table populated?  My guess is through an application or import, (something other than hardcoded values that you control) and there are hidden characters in your data.

Comment: Agree with @AaronDietz I was just looking at this post to see how you would determine that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442867/check-if-field-contains-special-character-in-sql

Comment: if you use `Like %on%` do you get the missing names and more?  if so then you have non-display characters at the end you need to handle.  Nikhil's response may work; or maybe you have tabs or  carriage return [char(10)]+linefeed [Char(13)] you need to handle...  or other characters...

Comment: The rows are being imported back from an sql export using ---- Surname varchar(50) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,----- Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

try using trim() function maybe because of spaces remaning rows are not being fetched.

```
Select * from MyDB.myTable where trim(myTable.Surname) LIKE '%on';
```

Comment: trim will remove spaces if any from the end of surname

Answer (score -4):

Try this:
    //tested with a varchar(100)
    SELECT * FROM `myTable` where myTable.Surname like '%on'

Comment: Add an explanation that explains why this will work and why OP's current code isn't working.