# Need a query returns the records which contains different characters of a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

On Sql Server 2012, I need a query which will return the records that contains any different character out of selection.

As instance, my field name is "description". If any letter in query in "description" field contains any character which is not in any of the conditions below, it should be listed:

numbers (0-9), letters (a-z), some other regional letters (öçşğüıÖÇŞİĞÜ), some signs (-,.&) and space ( )

Thanks

Edit: I've asked the same on my previous post which is closed, I asked the same and tried to be more descriptive.

Comment: Duplicate of closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800606/sql-query-returns-only-the-field-contains-spesific-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558755/how-to-detect-if-a-string-contains-special-characters) might be a good start. It shows how to use regular expression like syntax to determine if certain characters are in a field

EDIT

```
select * from [TABLE] where [FIELD] LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9öçşğüıÖÇŞİĞÜ-\& \.]%'
```

Comment: And how can I get the invert the results? I need the ones which doesn't fit with the expression.

Comment: That will return the rows that have characters outside of the specified ones....the [`^`...] means not in

Answer (score 3):

I would probably approach this with a tally table solution. You'll need a numbers table, either a TVF or a physical table but this should work

```
-- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/
--
WITH SRC (row_id, description) AS
(
    SELECT 1, N'normal text'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, N'bad text ¥1,235'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, N'normal text öçşğüıÖÇŞİĞÜ'
)
, ALLOWABLE (unicode_character) AS
(
    -- Define your known universe of allowed characters
    -- A-Z
    SELECT CAST(CHAR(GN.number + 64) AS nchar(1)) AS x
    FROM
        dbo.GenerateNumbers(26) AS GN
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST((GN.number -1) AS nchar(1)) AS x
    FROM
        dbo.GenerateNumbers(10) AS GN

    -- ...
    UNION ALL SELECT N' '
    UNION ALL SELECT N'ö'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'ç'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'ş'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'ğ'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'ü'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'ı'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'Ö'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'Ç'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'Ş'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'İ'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'Ğ'
    UNION ALL SELECT N'Ü'
)
, EXPLODED AS
(
    SELECT
        S.*
    ,   GN.number
    ,   SUBSTRING(S.description, GN.number, 1) AS individual_character
    FROM
        SRC S
        CROSS APPLY
            -- choose a large enough value      
            dbo.GenerateNumbers(30) AS GN  
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    E.row_id
,   E.individual_character      
FROM
    EXPLODED E
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ALLOWABLE A
        ON A.unicode_character =  E.individual_character
WHERE
    A.unicode_character IS NULL;
```