# Check Constraint- Check password contains atleast one number/special Character/uppercase

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraint

I'm looking to create three separate check constraints for my SQL Server database to ensure that a  password field constrains a minimum of one number, one uppercase character and one special character.

I consider the best way to approach is by creating separate check constrains for example I have created the following constraint to ensure that password length is a minimum of 8

`(len([password]) <= (8))`

Could any one suggest a way to establish the required validation.

Thanks

Comment: Do ***not*** store passwords in plain text!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with one constraint, something like:

```
check password like '%[0-9]%' and password like '%[A-Z]%' and password like '%[!@#$%a^&*()-_+=.,;:'"`~]%' and len(password) >= 8
```

Just a note about the upper case comparison:  this requires that the collation being used be case sensitive.  You may need to specify an explicit `COLLATE` in the comparison to be sure that it is case sensitive.

Comment: The special character and number constraint work perfectly, could you think of a reason why the capital letter constraint doesn't work?

Comment: @Matt_Johndon . . . The capital letter constraint depends on the collation of the strings involved (and the default collation for the database).  You'll need to use the `COLLATE` keyword to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I did not know answer for your question directly, but after some research i found this methods:

1) Check if given string contains uppercase character

```
SELECT CASE WHEN BINARY_CHECKSUM([password]) = BINARY_CHECKSUM(LOWER([password])) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS DoesContainUpperCase
GO
```

source: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic800271-338-1.aspx

2) Check if given string contains at least one special character

We can make simply statement

```
IF ([password] LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%')
```

source: [How to detect if a string contains special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558755/how-to-detect-if-a-string-contains-special-characters)

I hope my answer helped you.
Kind regards,

Rafal

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the 'a' in the collection of special characters and added the collate mentioned above.  Thanks for your help!

```
([password] like '%[0-9]%' AND [password] like '%[A-Z]%' collate Latin1_General_BIN2 AND [password] like '%[!@#$%^&*()-_+=.,;:~]%' AND len([password])>=(8))
```