# MYSQL search if a string contains special characters?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select

I need to search table field contains special characters. I found a solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558755/how-to-detect-if-a-string-contains-special-characters) something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tableName` 
WHERE `columnName` LIKE "%#%" 
OR `columnName` LIKE "%$%" 
OR (etc.)
```

But this solution is too broad. I need to mention all the special characters. But I want something which search something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tableName`
WHERE `columnName` LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

That is search column which contains not only a-z, A-Z and 0-9 but some other characters also. Is it possible with `MYSQL`

Comment: Does anyone know the answer for the same question but in Snowflake instead of MySQL? I tried below mentioned solution but it did not work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `regexp`

```
SELECT *
FROM `tableName`
WHERE `columnName` REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

This would select all the rows where the particular column contain atleast one non-alphanumeric character.

or

```
REGEXP '[^[:alnum:]]'
```

Comment: I was looking for any non alphanumeric also. But, I also wanted to allow hyphen and spaces.  This the regex I used for that.  REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9[.hyphen-minus.][.space.]]'

Comment: `I was looking for any non alphanumeric also`, I think space, hyphen is also an non-alphanumeric number.

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks.